# Error ORA-01400 while executing request INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables `ISSUENCE` and `SKLAD`.

In the `ISSUENCE` table, I am trying to make a request to insert the name of an item from the `SKLAD` table by its `ID`. Values entered in the table `ISSUENCE`:

```
ISSUE_ID, EPLOYEES_EMP_ID, SKLAD_ITEM_ID
```

Query used:

```
INSERT INTO issuence (issue_item_name) 
    SELECT item_name 
    FROM sklad, issuence 
    WHERE item_id = sklad_item_id;
```

But I am getting this error:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SKLAD"."ISSUENCE"."ISSUE_ID")

The tables look like this:

ISSUENCE:

[image]

SKLAD:

[image]

Comment: Hi - what about the error message is unclear to you? If you look at the table definition you can see which columns are not nullable

Comment: Well you try to insert null into ISSUE_ID, but "cannot insert NULL into ("SKLAD"."ISSUENCE"."ISSUE_ID")". What seems to be the trouble?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Are you trying to insert _new_ rows into the ISSUENCE table or _update_ ISSUE_ITEM_NAME of existing rows using the value of ITEM_NAME in the SKLAD table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post all information regarding that schema, but - looking at screenshots you posted - it seems that `item_id` is a primary key in `sklad` table which is then referenced by `sklad_item_id` column from `issuence`. Also, `issue_id` is probably primary key column in `issuence`. Irrelevant in this case, `employees_emp_id` looks like yet another foreign key column.

As you're on 11g, primary key columns aren't *identity columns* and their value can't be generated automatically in a *declarative* manner. It means that you either have to provide primary key values while inserting rows into tables, or use database triggers which will do that.

Create tables:

```
SQL> create table sklad
  2  (item_id           integer constraint pk_sklad primary key,
  3   item_name         varchar2(500),
  4   form_size         varchar2(10),
  5   item_quantity     integer
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> create table issuence
  2  (issue_id          integer constraint pk_iss primary key,
  3   employees_emp_id  integer not null,
  4   sklad_item_id     integer constraint fk_iss_sklad references sklad (item_id) not null,
  5   issue_date        date,
  6   issue_period_days integer,
  7   issue_quantity    integer,
  8   issue_item_name   nvarchar2(200)
  9  );

Table created.
```

Sequence will be used for primary key columns:

```
SQL> create sequence seq_is;

Sequence created.
```

Sample `sklad` row:

```
SQL> insert into sklad (item_id, item_name) values (seq_is.nextval, 'Some name');

1 row created.
```

Here's where you got an error: you must provide values to `NOT NULL` columns, one way or another (trigger or manually). Here's an example:

```
SQL> insert into issuence (issue_id, employees_emp_id, sklad_item_id)
  2  select seq_is.nextval, 100, s.item_id
  3  from sklad s
  4  where s.item_id = (select min(a.item_id)
  5                      from sklad a);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from issuence;

  ISSUE_ID EMPLOYEES_EMP_ID SKLAD_ITEM_ID ISSUE_DATE ISSUE_PERIOD_DAYS ISSUE_QUANTITY ISSUE_ITEM
---------- ---------------- ------------- ---------- ----------------- -------------- ----------
         2              100             1

SQL>
```